# unable to use 'include_docs' in fetchRevs as it is neither in BulkFetchDocsWrapper interface nor in DocumentFetchParams interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, couchdb, couchdb-nano

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb1cc0e143f40f52a8d771e93036fc211df85cfb/types/nano/index.d.ts#L160

i am new to couch db and i know, i can use "fetch" if i want doc in result but i want doc in result based on some conditions when called with start_key and end_key. any help would be appreciated.

```
    fetchRevs(
  docnames: BulkFetchDocsWrapper,
  params: DocumentFetchParams,
  callback?: Callback<DocumentFetchRevsResponse>
  ): Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchRevs` endpoint is probably not what you want. I would take a look at the [CouchDB API Overview](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/api.html) and use:

- `PUT /mydb` to create a database
- `PUT /mydb/docid` to create a document in a database
- `GET /mydb/_all_docs?include_docs=true` to retrieve all the documents
- `POST /mydb/_find` to query the database

These API endpoints are modelled in the Typescript definition file you reference together with URLs that reference the API equivalents.

Comment: thanks for help.. :) i have checked out the documentation, in my case i have to use fetchRevs as it take some parameters like startkey endkey etc. along with include_docs parameter which is missing in the typescript definition, i have manually include that in the definition file for now to make it work. just a hack to make that work

Comment: The `fetch` function is the same as `fetchRevs` but has `include_docs` set to true by default. See source code here https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano/blob/master/lib/nano.js#L516-L547

Comment: yes it is and it is working fine if i am not using typescript,but in its typed definition we can't use include_docs in fetch_Revs as it is not present in the interface itself in the definition of fetch_Revs